# what are the dangers of using a Mutable thisarg or context with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and wonder about the wisdom using a mutable thisarg for functions like map, foreach, and filter.

Consider the following

```
function increasingValueFn(i)
{
    if (this.highestValue < i)
    {
        this.highestValue = i;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That function will allow us to pass in an object as thisarg, as in the following examples.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7];

console.log(arr.filter(increasingValueFn, {highestValue: 0}));
// outputs [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

and using the same increasingValueFn

```
var arr2 = ["cat", "dog", "aardvark", "zebra"];
console.log(arr2.filter(increasingValue, {highestValue: ""}));
// outputs ["cat", "dog", "zebra"]
```

Those are simple examples.  Imagine the case where we're trying to create a much more arbitrary answer with very complicated rules for inclusion, in which case we could make arbitrary changes to our state, and then run a simple predicate based on that state that returns yes or no.

However, I've not seen any examples of this online, and I realize this doesn't fit nicely into functional programming due to the mutation.

But am I fundamentally doing it wrong by doing it this way?  Is there a better way?

Should I be passing in a function that hides the internal state in a variable instead of passing in the state as thisarg?  That would preclude the following example, which allows us to partially evaluate the state, by doing the following:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7];
var arr1 = [3, 7, 9, 4, 2, 12];
var context = {highestValue: 0};

console.log(arr.filter(increasingValue, context));
// outputs [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]

// now using the **same** context, continue with arr1
console.log(arr1.filter(increasingValue, context));
// outputs [9, 12]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what the issue is.

Comment: This is to some extent a matter of taste (and perhaps other things, depending on the details of your design) but since you don't actually need to use the thisArg, you're better off avoiding it. It's there to deal with the warts in Javascript's handling of 'this' (some of which are fixed in ES6's arrow notation). In your examples, there's nothing stopping you from using a captured variable instead and it's a lot easier to follow.

Comment: [an implementation using Array.prototype.reduce](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=var%20arr%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%2C%202%2C%201%2C%205%2C%206%2C%207%5D%3B%0A%0Avar%20r%20%3D%20arr.reduce((acc%2C%20v)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20if%20(acc.length%20%3D%3D%3D%200%20%7C%7C%20v%20%3E%20acc%5Bacc.length%20-%201%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20acc.push(v)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20return%20acc%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(r)%3B)

Comment: @pvg there is a reason to not use free variables: then you would not be able to use the function again without an explicit reset. Hidden state is bad.

Comment: @zerkms it's not entirely obvious from the question what kind of reuse is wanted and there are generally perfectly good workarounds. The problem with this approach (and I do know that it's not all that uncommon) is that it hijacks a mechanism intended for something else for questionable benefits and a reduction in clarity.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the example using reduce, and the accumulator.  I agree that in this case, it can be rewritten like that, however, it requires you to produce the entire array before any values can be used, but might be useful in other cases for me.

Comment: "it requires you to produce the entire array before any values can be used" --- built-in data structures are strict, so you always have to produce it entirely before consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might read better as

```
var increasingFrom = function(init) {
    var highestValue = init;
    return function(i) {
        if (highestValue < i) {
            highestValue = i;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
}

console.log(arr.filter(increasingFrom(0)));
```

Comment: That is arguably saner but doesn't really answer the question why.

Comment: So with this implementation, anything that could be passed as thisarg, can be passed instead to init, and the state can be permuted in exactly the same way.

If you want to reset the state, you need to call increasingFrom(newInit) value again.  This style eliminates 'this.' as well.

Comment: This style means you don't need to remember the implementation of `increasingValue` when invoking it (ie, the name of the property to put initial state in)